# Fisher Matrix and Hessian matrix

Tags: statistics, matrix-calculus, regression-analysis, logistic-regression

I know that the Fisher matrix is easily obtained from the Hessian matrix
$I\left(\hat{\beta}\right)=-H\left(\hat{\beta}\right)$

Why is the covariance variance matrix the inverse of the Fisher information matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Let $l(z,\theta) = \ln p_{\theta}(z)$. As you said,
$$ I(\theta) = -\mathbb{E}_{\theta}(\nabla^2_{\theta} l(Z,\theta)). $$
Calculating the Hessian, you have
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla^2_{\theta} l(z,\theta))  &= \nabla_{\theta}\left(\dfrac{1}{p_\theta(z)}\nabla_\theta p_\theta (z) \right)\\
 &=\dfrac{-\nabla_\theta p_\theta(z)\nabla_\theta p_\theta(z)^T}{p_\theta(z)^2} + \dfrac{\nabla^2 _{\theta}p_\theta(z)p_\theta(z)}{p_\theta(z)^2}.
\end{align}
$$
But the left side of this equation is 
$$\dfrac{-\nabla_\theta p_\theta(z)\nabla_\theta p_\theta(z)^T}{p_\theta(z)^2} = -\nabla_\theta(\ln p_\theta (z))\nabla_\theta(\ln p_\theta (z))^T, $$
hence
$$
\begin{align}
I(\theta) &= -\mathbb{E}_{\theta}(\nabla^2_{\theta} l(Z,\theta))\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{\theta}(\nabla_\theta(\ln p_\theta (z))\nabla_\theta(\ln p_\theta (z))^T -\mathbb{E}_{\theta}(\dfrac{\nabla^2 _{\theta}p_\theta(z)}{p_\theta(z)})\\
&= Cov(\nabla_\theta(\ln p_\theta (z))) - \int\dfrac{\nabla^2 _{\theta}p_\theta(z)}{p_\theta(z)}p_\theta(z)dz \\
&=Cov(\nabla_\theta(\ln p_\theta (z))) - \int\nabla^2 _{\theta}p_\theta(z)dz \\
&\overset{*}{=}Cov(\nabla_\theta(\ln p_\theta (z))) - \nabla^2_{\theta}\int p_\theta(z)dz \\
&  = Cov(\nabla_\theta(\ln p_\theta (z))) - \nabla^2_{\theta}(1) \\
&=Cov(\nabla_\theta(\ln p_\theta (z))) + 0 ,\\
\end{align}
$$

where in $*$ you must use some extra condition that allow differentiation under the integral sign with respect to $\theta.$

**Edit:**

I think I didn't quite answer your question. 
Actually, we can show that (under some assumptions) the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) $\hat{\theta}_n$is asymptotically normal with mean $\theta_p$ (the parameter you are estimating) and covariance matrix $I(\theta_p)^{-1}$. That is, 
$$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_p) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,I(\theta_p)^{-1}), $$

where $\overset{d}{\rightarrow}$ stands for convergence in distribution.

For some references, I suggest 'Asymptotic Statistics' by Aad van der Vaart; 'Theoretical Statistics:Topics for a Core Course' by R.W. Keener and these links:

- https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/maximum-likelihood
- https://www.statlect.com/glossary/information-matrix

Comment: You can sugest any book to find this?

Comment: I updated my answer, hope this helps.